# Merge multiple rows into one in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert a pandas dataframe with multiple rows into one row

```
     col1.    col2.    col3.    col4.    col5.
0    1234     rule_1.  ''       ''       ''
1    1234     ''       rule_2.  ''       ''
2    2356     rule_1.  ''       ''       ''
3    7890     ''       ''       rule_3   ''
4    1234     ''       ''       ''       rule_4
```

I need to groupby by col1. and fill in the empty fields with the fields from the other rows.

```
     col1.    col2.    col3.    col4.    col5
0    1234     rule_1.  rule_2   ''       rule_4
1    2356     rule_1.  ''       ''       ''
3    7890     ''       ''       rule_3   ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC first mask the '' to nan , then we do `groupby` + `first`

```
s=df.mask(df=="''").groupby('col1.').first()
s # you can add reset_index()
         col2.    col3.   col4.   col5.
col1.                                  
1234   rule_1.  rule_2.     NaN  rule_4
2356   rule_1.      NaN     NaN     NaN
7890       NaN      NaN  rule_3     NaN
```

Comment: That is a slick solution!